# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Travel's [fourth moderator election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Willeke]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), who is stepping down, for their service as moderator since 2013.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5154809896239104/0).

Comment: @Willeke Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations to the new mod!

Comment: Yay! Go @Willleke!

Comment: Congrats Willeke!

Comment: Congratulations Willeke! You're going to do an awesome job!

Comment: Hartelijk gefeliciteerd !

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: You know, I was just wondering where Roflcoptr has been.

Comment: Van harte gefeliciteerd!

Answer (score 6):

Users may not have noticed, but the voting was at an all-time high for this Stack.  Quite impressive.  (No moderator election here has had this many votes, ever.)